# Deploying a Rails Api only project do digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

I have been scratching my head for days reading docs and guides on how to deploy rails applications to digital ocean, the problem is my trying to deploy an api only project and all the guides seem to work only for full rails projects.

I have no idea what im doing wrong or what is wrong, ive followed this guide https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/20.04, I tried digital oceans marketplace rails offering, and ive read and tried to follow many other guides. I go through all the steps, everything seems to build successfully, i dont get any errors, but when I go to the public IP for my DO box i just get a page not found, ive messed with the nginx config, tried setting it up with a brand new rails project, and tried changing countless config files yet i have no idea what im doing wrong.

I dont really know what my question is since I dont really know where the problem lies, but does anyone have any resources detailing how to deploy a react api project to a digital ocean droplet?

I also tried digital oceans App Platform, it builds successfully but no data is served, the server just doesnt respond. I can ssh into it, setup all the ssh keys and setup automatic builds but thats as far as it works.

So if anyone has any articles, guides, or documentation that I could read that detail rails api deployments id really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Deploying an api Rails app is exactly the same as deploying a full app.

Comment: Was on my way to answer my own question, you are correct, my issue was that I wasnt routing nginx to proxy requests to the api. thank you for the comment! its my first time using DO, previously i just used heroku so my deploy experience is rather limited

Comment: What are you using to deploy? Just out of curiosity.